# System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: LIMIT_EXCEEDED, limit exceeded: []

Tags: dmlexception

Users started receiving limit exceeded error while trying to save a CASE from this afternoon and it appears to be sporadic (it gets saved after multiple attempts) but happening 80% of the times. In debug logs, it shows "EXCEPTION_THROWN|[629]|System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: LIMIT_EXCEEDED, limit exceeded: []" but not sure what went wrong. I have made sure that there no SOQL limt exceptions in the logs and also, nothing was changed/deployed in past one week (neither configuration nor code changes). Any thoughts?

Comment: Without looking at the code, it would be impossible to identify what went wrong.

Comment: Also, it looks like a DML limit exception, not SOQL.

Comment: Quite possibly being caused by accumulated DMLs and not just the single save being attempted. Take a look into the logs and find out where your limits are being consumed within this users transaction.

Comment: Right, I have checked for accumulated DMLs (in logs till the exception point), and it doesn't come closer. Also, I am curious, why it started mid of the day which has been up and running for past 6 months.

Comment: this is last LIMIT USAGE just above the exception.  Number of SOQL queries: 27 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 38 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 2 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 2 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 386 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.. we have Omni channel enabled and case count in the the queue has reached the limit.

Comment: You may want to mark this as best answer and close this thread.

Comment: I think I need to wait for 48 hours to do so.